# I don't understand why I got a JSP syntax error . (mutiple annotation)

Tags: java, jsp

(I got the source code from Google search. I was typing some code myself to learn. I triple checked and my typing is  the same as the source. I even copied and pasted it, but still got the same error.)

```
<% UserBean currentUser = (UserBean (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%>
```

In the JSP file, I'm getting a syntax error here. I attached a screenshot of its details.  I made Userbean.java  and setAttribute "currentSessionUser" earlier.

[image]

Here is the full code of that JSP page. (html tags doesn't appear in the code, so I added a screenshot. **(Minor question)** Is there a way to show html tags here? 
 < > doesn't seem to work here.)

[image]

> Can anyone guess why I'm getting a syntax error?

I've tried
`<% UserBean currentUser = (UserBean (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")));%>   //three closing brackets`

`<% UserBean currentUser = UserBean (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%>  //removing the bracket in front of UserBean`

Comment: <% UserBean currentUser = (UserBean 
            (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")));%>   //three closing brackets. This looks good. Have you tried clean building the application?

Comment: @RiyaGeorge  I think the writer of this code forgot to close ) in UserBean casting. thank you for your comment~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <% UserBean currentUser = (UserBean (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%>
```

Simply count the number of left and right brackets. 
But what you look like you want to do is `cast`

so

```
UserBean currentUser = (UserBean) (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));
```

BTW, maybe better to use EL in your JSP, not java

Comment: ah~~~ casting!  I didn't think of that . thank you very much~ Yup I'll use EL.